# Does String.IndexOf(Char) always point to the same Char?

Tags: .net, string, .net-3.5, indexof

I'm reviewing some existing code (converted from C#). It currently includes this expression:

```vb
Value.Substring(Value.IndexOf(symbol), 1)
```

where `symbol` *is* a `Char` from `Value`, a `String`. (Yes, it is from `For Each symbol As Char In Value`.)

As far as I can tell from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) this will be identical to:

```vb
symbol.ToString
```

(which will be much faster).

Can anyone suggest any situation when this won't be the case?

Note I do see the "flaw" in this code that means it may refer to an earlier version of `symbol` in `Value` than the one we're really considering, but that is part of my question: can this ever actually matter?

(Obviously another solution is to rework the code to `For i = 0 To Value.Length - 1: symbol = Value(i): ... Value.Substring(i, 1) ...` to keep the reference to the original string, just in case.)

```vb
    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is a different Url Encode implementation since the default .NET one outputs the percent encoding in lower case.
    ''' While this is not a problem with the percent encoding spec, it is used in upper case throughout OAuth
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Value">The value to Url encode</param>
    ''' <returns>Returns a Url encoded string</returns>
    Public Function UrlEncode(ByVal Value As String) As String
        Dim result As New StringBuilder()

        For Each symbol As Char In Value
            If unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) <> -1 Then
                result.Append(symbol)
            Else
                'some symbols produce > 2 char values so the system urlencoder must be used to get the correct data
                Dim hexAscW As String = String.Format("{0:X2}", CInt(AscW(symbol)))
                If hexAscW.Length > 3 Then
                    result.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Value.Substring(Value.IndexOf(symbol), 1)).ToUpper())
                Else
                    result.Append("%"c & hexAscW)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return result.ToString()
    End Function
```

I've already refactored the `hexAscW` which was originally a duplicated expression.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It sounds like you clearly have some bigger picture here, but it's not really clear what it is.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is not clear. Can you provide a sample string which demonstrates  your concerns?

Comment: Hmmm... Googling for `"Value.Substring(Value.IndexOf(symbol), 1)"` actually finds quite a few exact matches ...

Comment: @JonSkeet This is from an OAuth implementation I've just received. The comment for the `UrlEncode` implementation says it can't use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` in general because it needs the percent encoding in upper case, so it only uses it when the `AscW` value is > `255` (although it determines it based upon the length of the hex value). It uses this expression to "locate" the character in the string to pass to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, the result of which it `.ToUpper`s.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't have an example. That's my question, is `Value.Substring(Value.IndexOf(symbol), 1)` ever not equivalent to `symbol.ToString` when `symbol` is definitely present in `Value`?

Comment: It's somewhat hard to follow the description - it would be much simpler if you could just post the code you're looking at.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added the code. Note I know the comments regarding "some symbols produce > 2 char values" is effectively crap. Remember this is third party code twice removed :-)

Comment: Again "symbols produce > 2 char values" produces the same Google hits...

Comment: This code just looks confused. Not only is the index search unnecessary, the resulting index might be different than the index of `symbol`. Anyway, the question is valid.

Comment: One significant issue here is how surrogate pairs are *meant* to be handled. I've no idea what URL encoding is meant to do at that point. I'd be interested in what *needs* the URL encoding to be upper case, too...

Comment: @JonSkeet It looks like this issue has been discussed on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/918019/256431 ".net UrlEncode - lowercase problem").

Comment: FYI My [final version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25642368/256431) of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ?
Answering the question in the title.
Does String.IndexOf(Char) always point to the same character Char?
From the documentation yes.

[String.IndexOf Method (Char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified
>   Unicode character in this string.

Comment: Where in the question have you identified that IndexOf does not behave as documented? "first occurrence"  So the char may occur more than once in the string. Have you found a single case where IndexOf does not return the first occurrence?

Comment: I don't expect `IndexOf` to not behave as documented; that's why I believe the expression in the OP can be changed to just `symbol.ToString`.

Comment: Read your title.  Does String.IndexOf(Char) always point to the same Char?

Comment: Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified Unicode character in this string.

Comment: Because, as implied by other comments in this question and the one I linked to in my comment, the code needed much refinement, and noone has suggested there's a reason why my optimisation would have been wrong in isolation, I have given you the green tick.